# Shallow water model for year-round watershed runoff

Tags: numerical-modelling

I have an (maybe not so clever) idea to apply the shallow water model for computing the year-round watershed runoff of a catchment. It means using of real topography with variable slopes and roughness, length of the real time period about 31536000 seconds, real precipitation, temperature, snow cover and other data, etc. I read some books and papers about hydrodynamic models and many, many numerical methods for solving them. Shallow water model is usually applied for oceanic circulation, tides and estuaries, flood waves with relatively short time duration, etc. There are plenty of methods, described in the literature, like explicit and implicit ones, finite difference, finite volume, finite element, and so on. Every class of methods has its own pros and cons. There are also different flow regimes, different types of initial and boundary conditions, different conditions of the flow over the bottom, for example wet/dry conditions, etc. Not to mention some other processes and models like infiltration and porous media model which are also natural (but at the beginning only the shallow water model is important).

So, the questions are:

1. Is this idea even applicable and doable (this is especially about year-round duration of the time period)?
2. Which numerical methods are simple and stable, for starting the project, solving the shallow water model, and obtaining reasonable results at the beginning (which means positive water height, oscillations as small as possible, etc.)?
3. Which numerical methods are not so simple but yet stable, for advanced modelling, and obtaining better results with the shallow water model?

I appreciate every comment, suggestion, and advise.